# Map String values processing

Tags: java, dictionary, hashmap, jackson

I have Map like

```
for (Emp emp: findAllEmp()) {
Map<String, String> map = objectMapper.convertValue(emp, HashMap.class);  
}
```

which has values as

```
projects = {projectId=24, projectName=K245}
```

I would like to add if projects is not null, then add this to

```
map.put("projectId", map.get("projects.projectId}"));
map.put("projectName",map.get("projects.projectName}"));
```

When I see the output, `projects.projectId` and `projects.projectName` is always null.
How do I resolve this?

And how can I dynamically add values instead of hard coding `projects.projectId`?

Comment: How do you define and populate `em`?

Comment: @Mena that was a typo, I have corrected it.

Comment: @Polppan p ls post the data for `emp`

Comment: @ankur-singhal I have edited my question, data for emp is from DAO.

Comment: You probably want to have your own `Project` and some sort of `ProjectWrapper` types to de-serialize to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to understand,

`projects = {projectId=24, projectName=K245}` is nothing but

```
Map<String, Map<String,Object>>

Map<"projects", Map<"projectId",24>>
                Map<"projectName",K245>>
```

**Just iterate over a map**,

```
Map<String, String> map = objectMapper.convertValue(emp, HashMap.class);

        Map<String, Object> myMap = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        if (null != map && map.size() > 0) {
            for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : map.entrySet())
                myMap.put(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
        }
```

`myMap` will contain data as

```
Map<"projectId",24>
   <"projectName",K245>
```

Also you can iterate and check for value if value is `instanceOf Map`

```
Map<String, Object> myMap = null;
        if (null != map && map.size() > 0) {
            for (Map.Entry<String, Object> entry : map.entrySet())
                if (entry.getValue() instanceof java.util.Map) {
                    myMap = (Map<String, Object>) entry.getValue();
                }
        }
```

or assign value to myMap and iterate over it.

Comment: myMap return as `projects = {projectId=24, projectName=K245}`

Comment: I have one small issue, my list contains the following full string `[{"empNo":"2390","empName":"JAMES","projects":{"projectId":209,"projectName":"Z560"}}]`. Here my expected output is `{"empNo":"2390","empName":"JAMES","projectId":"24","projectName":"K245"}` So what left is `{"projectId":"209","projectName":"Z560"}`

Comment: @Polppan basically you have array of `projects`, you need to write regex and replace the desired string with `""`